# PHP safety with include

Tags: php, security

How safe would you say this is?

```
$pages = array("about", "help", "login");
$pagesWithId = array("shownews", "showuser", "showfile");

if (in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
    include('includes/'.$_GET['page'].'.php');
    include('templates/'.$_GET['page'].'.html');
}

foreach ($pagesWithId as $page) {
    if (ctype_digit($_GET[$page])) {
        include('includes/'.$page.'.php');
        include('templates/'.$page.'.html');
    }
}
```

You see any potential threats?

Answer (score 3):

It's safe.

What's not safe is allowing someone to build an arbitrary URL which you then include.

Here you're limiting the possible replacements to one of several known quantities, therefore it is safe.